# How to setup Liquibase connection to MySQL via SSL in Spring Boot

Tags: mysql, spring-boot, liquibase

I have a simple Spring Boot application connecting to MySQL database. I need to connect over SSL with certificate.

I know I need a keystore with certificate. I don't know how to configure Liquibase to establish secured connection using that certificate. Can you point me to some documentation, please?

Answer (score 1):

you can try this connection string:

```
url: jdbc:mysql://<DB_IP>:3306/mytest?allowPublicKeyRetrieval=true&useSSL=true&serverTimezone=UTC&verifyServerCertificate=false&requireSSL=true&clientCertificateKeyStoreUrl=file:/etc/mysqlcerts/keystore_jdbc.jks&clientCertificateKeyStorePassword=<keystore_passwd>&trustCertificateKeyStoreUrl=file:/etc/mysqlcerts/truststore.jks&trustCertificateKeyStorePassword=<keystore_passwd>
```